# It seems obvious, but how to prove it formally?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a not decreasing, Lebesgue integrable function with finite integral over $[0,+\infty)$.

It seems obvious to me that $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_b^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=0$ then.

But how can one very formally show it?

And assumption about monotonicity is crucial here, yes?

Comment: Monotonicity is not needed here. Idea: $f=f^+ - f^-$. So $f^+=f^+ 1_{x \leq b}+f^+1_{x > b}$. What can you say about the integral of $f^+ 1_{x \leq b}$ as $b \to \infty$?

Comment: Obviously, a better title is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be
$$F = \int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
We have from the general rules of integration:
$$F = \int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_0^b f(x) \,\mathrm dx
+ \int_b^\infty f(x) \,\mathrm dx.$$
Therefore
$$\int_b^\infty f(x) \,\mathrm dx = F - \int_0^b f(x) \,\mathrm dx$$
and thus
$$\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_b^\infty f(x) \,\mathrm dx = F - \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b f(x) \,\mathrm dx = F - \int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx = F - F = 0.$$

Comment: In the context of Lebesgue's theory, the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_0^b f = \int_{[0,\infty)} f$ is not axiomatic, but derived from the axioms.  I might have included something on how that's done.

Answer (score 0):

Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: isnt above proof correct? can you write more about it?

Comment: ok, I see how to do it. using $f$ restrictions to $[n,+\infty)$, yeah?